# how can i create a relationship between two contacts in csv?

Tags: npsp

I have a NPSPDataImportTemplate.csv and i will put all the contact records so that it all the records i put will be imported automatically using data import wizard. In additional, i want to create a relationship between the two contact records. Otherwise I want Rizal will be the Husband of Maria. I want it automatically created also when i import the CSV.